# Is it possible to view unaccepted questions I have answered?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I did try to search but couldn't find anything similar.

If I look at my profile view, it's possible to see all of the questions that I have answered and the little vote count boxes are colour coded to indicate if my answer has been accepted.

If I look at the unanswered questions view, I can see all of the sites questions that don't have accepted answers.

Is there some way to combine these two views, so that I can see which questions I have answered where at least one of the answers (even if it's not mine) has been accepted.

Now and again, I look back over the questions I've answered, but not been accepted for, to see what happened (is more info needed, did somebody else provide a great solution etc) and it would be useful if there were some way to know when the state changed.

Possible suggestions would be a different colour code for questions on the profile view where another answer was accepted, or having the date an answer was accepted next to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact solution but what do you think about this?

[user:592182 isaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:592182%20isaccepted:0)

Comment: Nice try, but not really what I'm after, from what I can tell it shows all the answers where I wasn't accepted, whether or not the question has an accepted answer. So http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564697/virtual-functions-versus-callbacks/5564802#5564802 (no accepted answers) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510230/example-of-point-based-gravity-in-c/5510288#5510288 (somebody elses answer accepted) both show up. I'm looking for some way to view one half or the other.